# Custom iPhone UISlider to look like the iPod app volume control

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uislider

So I have a `UISlider` which I'm customizing with some images:

```
UIImage *stetchLeftTrack = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_blue.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:9.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
UIImage *stetchRightTrack = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_white.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:9.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
[volumeSlider setThumbImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_blob.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[volumeSlider setMinimumTrackImage:stetchLeftTrack forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[volumeSlider setMaximumTrackImage:stetchRightTrack forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I'm actually just trying to copy the volume controls as seen in the iPod app (which AFAIK you can't do in code). Because I'm using high res images, it draws everything huge on the app like so:
[image]

When actually the desired effect is:
[image]

If I scale down the actual images, I lose the quality and it looks rubbish and blurry! So I'm looking to do this in code but got a bit lost...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are the high res images for the iPhone retina desplay? If so, you should use the names `slider_blue@2x.png` for the high res image and `slider_blue.png` for a normal res image. The @2x image is (suprise), twice the size.

The SDK will then use the correct one based on the device.

Comment: Excellent Thanks! I've never seen that documented anywhere! Should this apply to the Default.png loading image too?

Comment: And yes, they were for the Retina screen.

Comment: Yep, basically applies to all image resources. Here are some other naming conventions for the iPhone/iPhone4/iPad display: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1686.html

Comment: You should use this for EVERY image in your bundle (Icon, Default, etc.)

Comment: Ah Icon. That's a good point. I know the app will get the 512x512 from the App store if you don't but thanks yea :)